# Seeking proofs of a limit expression of the gamma function

Tags: limits, gamma-function

I just started reading H. M. Edwards' *Riemann's Zeta Function* and I encountered an equation that I don't know how to prove. It's Equation (3) on page 8:
$$\Pi(s)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1·2\cdots N}{(s+1)(s+2)\cdots(s+N)}(N+1)^s.$$
Both rigorous proofs and informal intuitions are welcome. The definition of the gamma function is given by Equation (2) on the same page:
$$\Pi(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^sdx\quad(\Re s>-1).$$

Comment: Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^N x^s\left(1-\frac{x}{N}\right)^N\,dx$ (integrating by parts) and play with $N\to\infty$.

Comment: @metamorphy It's beautiful.

Comment: @metamorphy: Then why is $e=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$? This is the main idea of your method, which is absent in my mind.

Comment: What is your definition of $e$? (Looks confusing. You're reading material on higher transcendental functions and still seem to have questions on the elementary ones... The "method" is not "mine" - I see it in many books on special functions, which predominately start with studying the $\Gamma$ function - and the only thing not entirely trivial to me here is the justification of limit manipulations...)

Comment: (I would ask what is your background, but...) I suggest going step by step.

Comment: @metamorphy: I'm not a mathematician, but a programmer knowing only a bit of calculus. But somehow (through a daydream) I became interested in the Riemann hypothesis. So I bought this book. Looks like it's beyond my level. Could you suggest a book for a beginner like me before this text?

Comment: Well, I think the standard university courses on both real and complex analysis are necessary prerequisites (I'm not a native English speaker, so I can't suggest anything specific here). And any book on special functions (just for quick references, not for thorough reading), like [this one](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43491/).

Comment: @metamorphy: The problem is that this author is arguing in the preface that math students should study classic, primary sources, which are "banquets" compared to secondary, expository books or "sack lunches!" But it seems that only snacks are for me.

Comment: One update is that I just enrolled in a local university's continuing-education, undergraduate math program. It's a bit slow, looking at the curriculum. There are at most 2 math courses per semester, and it lasts for 2.5 years.

Comment: You gonna run ahead the crowd. Sorry I'll stop here.

Comment: Maybe the substitution of $e$ by its limit is not the most difficult step, but it solves the problem by providing the direction. In my limited understanding, it's the major step, or a hint.

Comment: It makes sense - my mind may pretty well be deformed already (though I'm a programmer too... hope moderators won't drop a brick over my head for an offtopic).

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating what's suggested in my comment above (somehow [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Euler's_definition_as_an_infinite_product) lacks a proof)...

Consider $I_n(s)=\displaystyle\int_0^n x^s\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\,dx$. Integrating by parts $n$ times, we see that
$$I_n(s)=\frac{n!}{n^n(1+s)\ldots(n+s)}\int_0^n x^{n+s}\,dx=\frac{n^{s+1}\cdot n!}{(1+s)\ldots(n+1+s)}.$$
Now we're going to apply [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) with $g(x)=x^s e^{-x}$ and
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}x^s \displaystyle\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n,& 0<x<n\\ \hfill 0,\hfill &\hfill x\geqslant n\hfill\end{cases}$$
which is valid because $f_n(x)\leqslant g(x)$ follows from $1-t\leqslant e^{-t}$.

This gives $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n(s)=\Pi(s)$. Your limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n(s)\frac{(n+1)^s(n+s+1)}{n^{s+1}}$ is the same.